# Ubuntu freezing heavily after a while of playing AOE II HD through wine

Tags: 22.04, freeze, amdgpu

I have an AMD computer (ryzen 7) with radeon gpu. I think that fact may be important because it was in the past for some crashes.

Whenever I am solely playing Age of empires 2 the hd version, my computer and the game start to lag really bad. It keeps happening well after exiting the game.

For some reason only a full shutdown makes it go away. A restart doesn't.

At some point I've been left on an initramfs console. [Here's what was on screen that time](https://photos.app.goo.gl/CE9hf9kV7fPiH3x87).

Some people suggest to show what's been on the var/log/syslog file right until that point so I printed the last 100 lines before the crash and you can see it [here](https://justpaste.it/bcf05).

PD: maybe its unrelated but I sometimes get SIGILL and SIGSEGV errors in chrome. Also when sharing screen it sometimes does the same that when playing AOEII.

Details of my computer
ThinkPad E15 Gen 2
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon G
GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Renoir

Using Xorg ($XDG_SESSION_TYPE = X11)